# Lighttpd config: get value from key-value array

Tags: lighttpd

I can define variables in lighttpd.conf like that:

```
myvar = "bar"
foo = myvar ## OK, this works
```

I can also define key-value array:

```
myarr = ("foo" => "bar", "lol" => "rofl") ## Also OK
```

But how can I access a value by key in this array?

```
someval = myarr["foo"] ## No,
someval = myarr("foo") ## No,
someval = myarr.foo ## No, all these doesn't work.
```

I've googled a lot, but didn't find an answer. I found a lot of examples of *defining* arrays in lighttpd.conf, but no one example of *reading* a value by key from it. You are my last hope, guys.

Comment: Actually [the docs](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_configuration) do use the `var.` prefix for custom variable definitions, but don't use it for variable access. E.g. `var.foo = 'bar'` and then e.g. `"socket" => foo + ".sock"`.